# Thunderbird can send emails over own mailserver, K-9 not

Tags: email, smtp, android, 504

I switched to K-9 and APG recently to send and recieve emails and be able to en- and decrypt emails on the go. I've setup my own email server quite a while ago and everything works fine in Thunderbird, but not in K-9. Sending emails from Google Mail to my own email address works but not the other way round. I always get the error:

> Negative SMTP reply: 504 5.5.2 : Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname

I searched around the internet and there are other K-9 users with the same error message, but i've found no solution. I don't think the problem is the hostname because i asume i would get errors in Thunderbird as well ReverseDNS is set up correctly.

**EDIT:**
It's not a problem about K-9, it's a problem with hostnames. I realized my HELO restrictions in postfix were to strict so edited them. Here is my HELO config from /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
    reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
   #reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
    permit
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_sender_login_mismatch,
    permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   #reject_unknown_client_hostname,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    permit
```

Commented out lines were previously active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the mail client problem.

There is related [bug report](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/issues/1399) on github. The [developer said](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/issues/1399#issuecomment-221076495) he did not consider it possible or necessary to implement HELO validation in this mobile mail client when sending SMTP, and clothe this bugreport.

There is proposed workaround - set up a mail server on the receiving of messages from clients on a port other than 25 (sugested 587/TCP) and disable HELO check. It is also a good idea to receive this port (587/TCP) mail only from authorized local clients.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up. I assume now that Google Mail omitts EHLO validation and that's why it works with K-9. I will check out your proposed solution.

Comment: It's not a mail client problem but a server problem, in this case a postfix configuration problem. I will accept this answer anyway because it got me on the right track!